Unable to fix "Error: fork/exec /lambda-entrypoint.sh: exec format error"
I have read extensively about this mysterious lambda-entrypoint.sh. Apparently it is part of the lambda base image and neeeds to be referenced/invoked in the Dockerfile ?
But I can not find a working template for it. Here is my Dockerfile and the results of using it to run a Containerized Lambda function:
# Use the official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11

WORKDIR /var/task

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY service /var/task/service
COPY lambda_function.py .
COPY *.py .

CMD ["lambda_function.lambda_handler"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/lambda-entrypoint.sh"]

The build command is:
docker build --platform linux/amd64 -t 123456.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/cdk-hnb659fds-container-assets-7890-us-east-1:my-user-metrics6 .

Here is the output of running a test event:
 {
  "errorType": "Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint",
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: 8ba540c9-9877-4a90-b094-e2836fd0bbc4 Error: fork/exec /lambda-entrypoint.sh: exec format error"
}


The problem was completely different: I had selected ARM (based on a misunderstanding of the platform).  By allowing the default X86 this error went away.
